# How to add Custom Columns in SmartTable?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am displaying the data in a smartTable. Now I would like to add one custom icon column. Is this possible ? So for example I have a SmartTable and a JSON model as shown below and I would like to display the JSON Model value in First Column as Text.

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.smartControls.SmartTable"
    xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar"
    xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable">
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar 
    id="smartFilterBar"
    entityType="Product">
    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
    <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
    key="Category" visibleInAdvancedArea="true"
    preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false">
    </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
    <smartTable:SmartTable 
    id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable"
    smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" 
    tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
    editable="false"
    entitySet="Products" 
    useVariantManagement="false"
    useTablePersonalisation="false" 
    header="Products" 
    showRowCount="true"
    useExportToExcel="false" 
    enableAutoBinding="true">
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
    </mvc:View>
```

and in onInit() method of controller I have the json model.

```
var oData = { "Text": "StackOverFlow"};
var oModel = sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example here:

[SAP Developer Guide - Smart table](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/be/d8274140d04fc0b9bcb2db42d8bac2/content.htm)

I did this in an application recently, with an oData service, should be similar with data from JSON Model. Here is what mine looks like:

```html
 <smartTable:SmartTable 
  id="gSmartTable"
  initialise="onSmartTable"
  beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable"
  showOverlay="onShowOverlay"
  entitySet="Employees" 
  smartFilterId="gSmartFilterBar" 
  tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
  useExportToExcel="false" 
  useVariantManagement="false" 
  useTablePersonalisation="true"
  persistencyKey="gSmartTable_Explored"
  header="Workers" 
  showRowCount="true"
  enableAutoBinding="true"
  demandPopin="true"> 
  
  
  
 <!-- Build table to handle custom field -->
  <Table id ="gEmployeesTable" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" growingThreshold="20">
   <columns>
   <Column width="100px" hAlign="Left">
     <customData>
      <!-- Custom Field -->
      <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
       value='\{"columnKey": "Pernr", "maxLength": "5","columnIndex":"0", "leadingProperty": "Pernr"}' />
     </customData>
      <Text text="{i18n>tableColumnEmployeeID}" />
    </Column>
    <Column width="100px" hAlign="Left">
     <customData>
      <!-- Custom Field -->
      <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
       value='\{"columnKey": "ZQ_STAT", "maxLength": "5","columnIndex":"4", "leadingProperty": "ZQ_STAT"}' />
     </customData>
      <Text text="{i18n>tableColumnStatus}" />
    </Column>
   </columns>
   <items>
    <!-- Table Navigation -->
    <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
     <cells>
      <!-- Use formatter to dispay Pernr -->
     <Text text="{
     path: 'Pernr',
     formatter: '.formatter.stripZeros'
     }" />
     </cells>
     <cells>
      <!-- Use formatter to dispay icon colour based on status field value (0,1,2,3) -->
      <core:Icon 
      src="{
       path: 'ZQ_STAT',
       formatter: '.formatter.iconVis'
       }" 
      color="{
       path: 'ZQ_STAT',
       formatter: '.formatter.iconColour'
       }"/>
     </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
   </items>
  </Table>
 <!-- End Custom Table -->
 
 <!-- End Smart Table -->
 </smartTable:SmartTable>
```

I was able to add two custom fields, with formatters on the data. If you want the custom column to appear first, set the 'columnIndex' property appropriately.

Hope that helps!